# Do values come into a Cloudant reducer in key order?

Tags: mapreduce, cloudant, reducers

I'm writing map/reduce code for a database on [Cloudant](https://cloudant.com/). Do the values come in to the `reduce(keys, values, rereduce)` function in key order when `rereduce=false`? I assume they would because that's how I am accustomed to things working in Hadoop, but I can't find anything in the Cloudant documentation that explicitly says they do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not guaranteed that values come into the reduce function in key order when rereduce=false.